# Can $2^n\pm n$ with $n>2$ be a triangular number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Recall that triangular numbers are those
$$T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}2\ \ (n=0,1,2,\ldots\}.$$

Clearly, $$2^1-1=1=T(1),\ \ 2^1+1=3=T(2),\ \ 2^2+2=6=T(3).$$

**Question.** Is there an integer $n>2$ with $2^n-n$ or $2^n+n$ a triangular number?

I guess the answer should be negative, but I don't know how to prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: See Question 306174 (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/306174) for similar topics involving perfect powers..

Comment: We at least need that $n$ is even. If $2^n +n = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ then, $2^{n+3} +4n = 4k(k+1) = 4k^2 + 4k = (2k+1)^2 -1$. So  $2^{n+3} +4n+1$ is a perfect square. If $n$ is odd and greater than 6, then this is clearly impossible since $2^{n+3}$ is then a perfect square and the next perfect square after that is greater than $2^{n+3} +4n+1$.  So we may assume that $n$ is even. Similarly, we can get that $n$ is even in the case of $2^n -n = T(k)$.

Comment: @JoshauZ $2^{n+3} + 8n = 4k(k+1)$. Am I right?

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi Ah yes, you are correct. So argument will still go through but one needs to assume n is at least 8 then to get a contradiction. (One can still check the other small n by hand.)

Comment: Do you know if $||\sqrt{2}\cdot 2^m||_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}} \le 100\frac{m}{2^m}$ for only finitely many $m \ge 1$? If so, your problem is solved.